# getpid(), WIFSHSTOPPED(state) to check child process sleeping

Tags: c, linux, fork, waitpid

Hello Im making program using 3 process P0,P1,P2
I wanna make a CYCLE like below

```
init: P0 P1,P2 paused, signal to P0
P0 : wake up by signal -> finish job -> signal to P3 -> pause
P1 : wake up by signal -> finish job -> signal to P2 -> pause
P2 : wake up by signal -> finish job -> signal to P3 -> pause
repeat 0~2
```

Unfortunatly, SOMETIMES signal comes before target process sleep

So I wanna check target process is paused or not.
I insert [checking code] like this

```
//end job here here
//
int status = 0;
do {
    waitpid(target_pid, &status, WNOHANG); // WNOHANG : check child status without waiting
} while ( ! WIFSTOPPED(status));           // linux man said that WIFSTOPPED
                                           // return true if process stopped
//signal to target_pid and pause() here
```

but it's not working.

if i use

```
 while( ! WIFSTOPPED(status))
```

program 100% can't get out of loop.

if I use

```
 while(   WIFSTOPPED(status))
```

It work as same as before I put [checking code]

I know that waitpid function is for checking process ends.

but CAN'T waitpid() JUST USED FOR CHECK PAUSED OR NOT?

Comment: Third instance of this homework:(

Comment: That's not how it works. I recommend you [read the `waitpid` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and check what it *returns*.

Comment: You mean "check stop" of WIFSTOPPED() is different from what I said?

Comment: What do you think it means for a process to be stopped? Your incomplete program fragment doesn't give us many clues, but you should know that neither `pause()` nor `sleep()` have anything to do with it. "Stopped" means "suspended".

Comment: `waitpid()`  (when not used in conjunction with a `ptrace`d process) needs `WUNTRACED` to receive `WIFSTOPPED` notifications.

Answer (score 1):

if `child` is completed `normally`( after delay got over) then you can use `WIFEXITED(status)`, it will be true if child has exited normally.

if child got `killed`(using kill command from other terminal) or suspended by any **signal** from other process or same process then you can use `WIFSIGNALED(status)`.

according to your requirement I modify your code as

```
int main()
{

        if(fork()==0) // p1
        {
                int t;
                srand(getpid());
                t = rand()%10 +1;//generating delay b/w 1 to 10 seconds
                printf("child1 delay : [%d] pid : [%d] ppid : [%d] \n",t,getpid(),getppid());
                sleep(t);
                printf("child1 pid : [%d] and its ppid : [%d] exiting \n",getpid(),getppid());
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                if(fork()==0) // p2
                {
                        int t;
                        srand(getpid());
                        t = rand()%10 +1;//generating delay b/w 1 to 10 seconds
                        printf("child2 delay : [%d] pid : [%d] ppid : [%d] \n",t,getpid(),getppid());
                        sleep(t);
                        printf("child2 pid : [%d] and its ppid : [%d] exiting \n",getpid(),getppid());
                        exit(1);
                }
                else // p3
                {
                        int status;
                        printf("In parent...[%d]\n",getpid());
                        int ret;
                        while((ret = waitpid(-1,&status,0))!=-1)//when there is no child left it returns -1
                        {
                                if(WIFEXITED(&status))//if child is completed normally after sleep is over
                                {
                                        printf("child [%d] terminates normally : %d\n",ret,WEXITSTATUS(status));
                                }
                                if(WIFSIGNALED(&status))//true if child was killed by any signal from other process or same process
                                {
                                        printf("child [%d] terminates normally : %d\n",ret,WTERMSIG(status));//it will print the signal no by which it was killed
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

there is no need to `pause()` because you should use `pause()` when one process should blocked until it is not received signal from other process.

Kindly go through man page of `waitpid()`.

Comment: Thank you for help. now I realize I used wrong function. waitpid is for detecting more critical problems, not  pause()

Comment: I should have to use other methods like proc/pid/status